# Eclipse Helios seems to be corrupted

Tags: eclipse

I am working on an application in Eclipse Helios and since yesterday every change in the code is not being applied when running the application. I have no idea what is going on. Is my Eclipse corrupted? Have some of you faced such situation? Many thaks.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably disabled the automatic build, so Eclipse never compiles your changes. Check the main menu Project -> Build automatically.

Comment: I checked it, but that is not the solution, unofortunately. I have even tried to download different version of Eclipse today and run the project there, but the result is the same - I even can delete some lines of the code, without which the program has no chance to start and it will start! Just getting crazy